# Django: The page isn't redirecting properly error

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm getting `the page isn't redirecting properly' coming up in my browser.  I'm trying to move an app to be in a sub-folder of another app (because logically it is a special case of that app).

This code is causing the loop, but I do not understand why.

```
if administration_instance.study.instrument.form in ['CAT'] : 
    return redirect('cat_forms:administer_cat_form', hash_id=hash_id)
```

My main urls.py have this line:

```
url(r'^form/', include('cdi_forms.urls')),
```

My `cdi_forms.urls` has this line:

```
url(r'fill/(?P<hash_id>[0-9a-f]{64})/$', views.administer_cdi_form, name='administer_cdi_form'),  #I've included this line because it is the url being called in the loop        
path('cat/', include(('cdi_forms.cat_forms.urls', 'cat_forms'), namespace="cat_forms")),
```

And my `cdi_forms.cat_forms.urls` has

```
path('fill/<hash_id>/', views.AdministerAdministraionView.as_view(), name='administer_cat_form'),
```

This generates a url `/form/cat/fill/614764fa0f135073bc6166ab560882da3a4ed674fcd7f05030583daa1e637230/` which is correct but it is calling the initial function which is at url `/form/fill/614764fa0f135073bc6166ab560882da3a4ed674fcd7f05030583daa1e637230/`.  The difference is the inclusion of `cat` in the former.

Why is it looping?

**EDIT**
As requested a complete list of urls in cdi_forms (and I've also included a complete list for cat_forms).

cdi_forms.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'demo/English_WS$', views.cdi_form, name='cdi_form'),
        url(r'background/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.BackgroundInfoView.as_view(), name='background-info'),
        url(r'background-create/(?P<study_id>[0-9]+)/bypass/$', views.CreateBackgroundInfoView.as_view(), {'bypass':True}, name='create-new-background-info'),
        url(r'background-create/(?P<study_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.CreateBackgroundInfoView.as_view(), {'bypass':None}, name='create-new-background-info'),
        url(r'background-backpage/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.BackpageBackgroundInfoView.as_view(), name='backpage-background-info'),
        url(r'fill/(?P<hash_id>[0-9a-f]{64})/$', views.administer_cdi_form, name='administer_cdi_form'),
        url(r'save_answer/$', views.save_answer, name='save_answer'),
        url(r'group/(?P<username>[^/]+)/(?P<study_group>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$', views.find_paired_studies, name='find_paired_studies'),
        url(r'contact/(?P<hash_id>[0-9a-f]{64})/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
        url(r'update_administration_data_item/$', views.update_administration_data_item, name="update-administration-data-item"),
        url(r'administraion-pdf-view/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PDFAdministrationDetailView.as_view(), name="administration-pdf-view"),
        url(r'administraion-view/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AdministrationDetailView.as_view(), name="administration-view"),
        path('cat/', include(('cdi_forms.cat_forms.urls', 'cat_forms'), namespace="cat_forms")),
]
```

cdi_forms.cat_forms.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('background/<int:pk>/', views.CATBackgroundInfoView.as_view(), name='background-info'),
    path('background-create/<int:study_id>/bypass/', views.CreateBackgroundInfoView.as_view(), {'bypass':True}, name='create-new-background-info'),
    path('background-create/<int:study_id>/', views.CreateBackgroundInfoView.as_view(), {'bypass':None}, name='create-new-background-info'),
    path('background-backpage/<int:pk>/', views.CATBackpageBackgroundInfoView.as_view(), name='backpage-background-info'),
    path('fill/<hash_id>/', views.AdministerAdministraionView.as_view(), name='administer_cat_form'),
    ]
```

**EDIT 2**

Added main urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="researcher_UI/home.html")),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/favicon.ico', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^robots\.txt', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/robots.txt', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^wcadmin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^form/', include('cdi_forms.urls')),
    #path('cat/', include(('cdi_forms.cat_forms.urls', 'cat_forms'), namespace="cat_forms")),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page': 'interface/'}),
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/interface/', permanent=False), name='interface'),
    url(r'interface/', include('researcher_UI.urls')),
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^lockout/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="registration/lockout.html")),
    url(r'^health/?', include('health_check.urls')),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `^` at the beginning of your regex. That means that this URL

```
 url(r'fill/(?P<hash_id>[0-9a-f]{64})/$', views.administer_cdi_form, name='administer_cdi_form'),
```

matches `fill/614764fa0f135073bc6166ab560882da3a4ed674fcd7f05030583daa1e637230` but it also matches `cat/fill/614764fa0f135073bc6166ab560882da3a4ed674fcd7f05030583daa1e637230`.

Change it to

```
 url(r'^fill/(?P<hash_id>[0-9a-f]{64})/$', views.administer_cdi_form, name='administer_cdi_form'),
```

The other `url()`s in your `cdi_forms/urls.py` and `url(r'interface/', ...)` in the main urls are also missing the `^`.